# How could one say that it doesnt exist while still its having a value?

Tags: calculus, limits

The doubt araised when I was in my class studying about iterated limits.

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}y\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big) $$

In the above limit, it's taught that the first limit do not exist thus the whole will not. But what my doubt is, when the first limit is operated we are getting $ y*k$ where $k$ is some value between $-1$ and $1$ ... so we have a value for that limit but don't know what it is. Then if we apply the next limit... It becomes zero... Can someone pls explain why we cannot do like as I thought

Comment: You are NOT getting $y\cdot k$ for some $ -1 \leq k \leq 1$, because $\sin(1/x)$ is **not** approaching a fixed value as $x \to 0$.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$? The answer is this doesn't exist. So it doesn't make sense to talk about "we are getting $y\times k$ where $k$ is some value between $-1$ and $1$".

Comment: So you are saying we cannot go to next step without having a fixed value for the first

Comment: But still if y is tending to zero... Won't the limit exist

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For $y\neq 0$, we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}y\sin(1/x)=\mathtt{undefined},$$ where the symbol $\mathtt{undefined}$ stands for the fact that no number is assigned to this limit. So the "limit" of this as $y\to0$ is still undefined.

Saying differently, this simply tells that the iterated limit $\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}$ does not properly capture the behavior of $y\sin(1/x)$ that OP is interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do things step by step, and the order matters very much. limit in $x$ first, then the limit in $y$, because that's your question. Because for any $y\neq 0$, $\lim_{x\to 0}y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ doesn't exist, neither does $\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

On the other hand, if you asked: "what is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \lim\limits_{y\to 0}y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$", then the answer is $0$, because we first fix a value of $x\neq 0$. Then, we are looking at $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. THis is zero, because $-1\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq 1$, so if we multiply by $y$, and let $y\to 0$ the result is $0$.

So,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}(0) = 0.
\end{align}

---

So, your reasoning is actually addressing a different question. And probably the reason you're confused is because intuitively, you may expect that $\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}$ is the same thing as $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}$. Unfortunately, IT IS NOT (and this example shows you exactly why the order matters)! Welcome to calculus/analysis; you'll encounter many such results which show you that you have to be very very careful with limits, the order of limits etc.

Comment: Thanks... May be the way I thought was wrong. I thought that even though the sin value isn't fixed it must be somewhere between the range and  proceeded with that logical reason. Still the thought is disturbing me, Hope I will be able to see things through soon